# RxJS pipe function disregarding observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am upgrading an app to RxJS from Promises and I am not entirely sure whether I am on the right track.

Case:
Given a ModalComponant that loads in when an HTTP request is sent and destroys when the response is received.
So what I do is as follows

```
public post(uri: string, body: object, showLoading: boolean = true, params: object = {}): Observable<any> {
if (showLoading) {
  this.toggleModal('open');
}

return this.http.post(
  this.createUrl(uri),
  body,
  this.createOptionsWrapper(params)
)
.pipe(
  this.toggleModal('close'),
  catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
);
```

}

*toggleModal()* accepts 1 parameter and based on that it will open/close the Modal. I understand pipeable Operators must return a OperatorFunction type. What do you reckon what is the most suitable RxJS Operator for the above case where I don't touch the Observable itself I merely want to make it pipeable so it runs in the given sequence? Might be worth creating a custom one myself? Of course the Observable being returned here will be piped again wherever the service is injected.

Comment: The rxjs website has an interactive [operator decision tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree). "I have one observable" -> "when it completes, errors or unsubscribes, I want to execute a function" leads you to `finalize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO `finalize` operator would be best fit here. It's invoked when the source completes or errors and will not modify the emission from the observable.

```js
public post(
  uri: string, 
  body: object, 
  showLoading: boolean = true,
  params: object = {}
): Observable<any> {
  if (showLoading) {
    this.toggleModal('open');
  }

  return this.http.post(
    this.createUrl(uri),
    body,
    this.createOptionsWrapper(params)
  ).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      if (showLoading) {
        this.toggleModal('close');
      }
    }),
    catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
  );
}
```

Comment: agree with finalize being correct, but should also wrap this in a `defer`

Comment: @bryan60: Would it make a big difference given the HTTP observable is cold?

Comment: It'd make a difference because the `toggleModal('open')` line would occur before the observable becomes hot, and if the observable never goes hot, then the modal never closes.

Answer (score 3):

@Michael D is correct IMO that `finalize` is the proper operator, but i also believe you should wrap this in a `defer`:

```
public post(uri: string, body: object, showLoading: boolean = true, params: object = {}): Observable<any> {
  return defer(() => {
    if (showLoading) {
      this.toggleModal('open');
    }

    return this.http.post(
      this.createUrl(uri),
      body,
      this.createOptionsWrapper(params)
    ).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.toggleModal('close')),
      catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
    );
  });
}
```

the reason being that observables have an expectation that they do nothing unless they're subscribed to. so if you just were building some conditional like so:

```
let save$ = this.service.post(...)
if (id) {
   save$ = this.service.put(...)
}
save$.subscribe();
```

the modal wouldn't get toggled UNTIL you actually subscribe. without defer, the modal would be toggled at line 1.  The general point being, that without `defer` you create situations where the modal may get opened and then never be closed if you never subscribe. using `defer` ensures that can never happen.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator if you don't want to modify the results of response.

```
return this.http.post(
  this.createUrl(uri),
  body,
  this.createOptionsWrapper(params)
)
.pipe(
      tap( () => this.toggleModal('close') ),
      catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
);
```